# Getting data-* attribute for onclick event for an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a id="option1" data-id="10" data-option="21" href="#" onclick="goDoSomething(?,?);">
       Click to do something
</a>
```

I want to get the `data-id` and `data-option` values inside the function `goDoSomething(10, 21)` I have tried to use `this` reference: `this.data['id']` but it did not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Here's an answer using vanilla JS https://stackoverflow.com/a/39670335/5049215

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can achieve this `$(identifier).data('id')` using **jquery**,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function goDoSomething(identifier){     
            alert("data-id:"+$(identifier).data('id')+", data-option:"+$(identifier).data('option'));               
        }

    </script>

    <a id="option1" 
       data-id="10" 
       data-option="21" 
       href="#" 
       onclick="goDoSomething(this);">
           Click to do something
    </a>
```

**javascript** : You can use `getAttribute("attributename")` if want to use javascript tag,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function goDoSomething(d){
            alert(d.getAttribute("data-id"));
        }

    </script>

    <a id="option1" 
       data-id="10" 
       data-option="21" 
       href="#" 
       onclick="goDoSomething(this);">
           Click to do something
    </a>
```

Or:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function goDoSomething(data_id, data_option){       

            alert("data-id:"+data_id+", data-option:"+data_option);
        }

    </script>

    <a id="option1" 
       data-id="10" 
       data-option="21" 
       href="#" 
       onclick="goDoSomething(this.getAttribute('data-id'), this.getAttribute('data-option'));">
           Click to do something
    </a>
```

Comment: As the author put the tag "jQuery", I recommend you to write the method with $(identifier).data('id') ;)

Comment: Thanks Maxime Lorant, Added the `Jquery` option also.

Answer (score 45):

Like this:

```
$(this).data('id');
$(this).data('option');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwHUc/

Answer (score 9):

I simply use this jQuery trick:

```
$("a:focus").attr('data-id');
```

It gets the focused `a` element and gets the `data-id` attribute from it.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the data attribute is present, then do the stuff...

```
$('body').on('click', '.CLICK_BUTTON_CLASS', function (e) {
                        if(e.target.getAttribute('data-title')) {
                            var careerTitle = $(this).attr('data-title');
                            if (careerTitle.length > 0) $('.careerFormTitle').text(careerTitle);
                        }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function get_attribute(){ alert( $(this).attr("data-id") ); }
```

Read more at
https://www.developerscripts.com/how-get-value-of-data-attribute-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

here is an example

```
 <a class="facultySelecter" data-faculty="ahs" href="#">Arts and Human Sciences</a></li>

    $('.facultySelecter').click(function() {        
    var unhide = $(this).data("faculty");
    });
```

this would set var unhide as ahs, so use .data("foo") to get the "foo" value of the data-* attribute you're looking to get

Comment: I'd rather `$('.facultySelecter').on("click", function() { var unhide = $(this).data("faculty"); });`

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use anchor id or data-action attributes  to trigger the event.

*Html Code*

```
<a id="option1" data-action="option1" data-id="10" data-option="21" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Here">Click Here</a>
```

*jQuery Code:*

```
$('a#option1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('id') + '::' + $(this).data('option')) ;   
});
```

OR

```
$('[data-action="option1"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('id') + '::' + $(this).data('option'));    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User `$()` to get `jQuery` object from your link and `data()` to get your values

```
<a id="option1" 
   data-id="10" 
   data-option="21" 
   href="#" 
   onclick="goDoSomething($(this).data('id'),$(this).data('option'));">
       Click to do something
</a>
```