# JavaScript - get attributes of clicked button

Tags: javascript

This answer explains how you can get the ID of a clicked button.

[JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

However, can you also get other attributes of that button? E.g. `name` or **[`data-* attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can you also get other attributes of that button?

In the click handler you have access to the event data which gives you access to:

- the DOM node that triggered the event (`e.target`)
- the DOM node that the event was bound to (`e.currentTarget`)
- all other event data (such as which mouse button was used for click events, event type, etc…)

The DOM node references have APIs for accessing data such as [their attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

*Additionally* the DOM node that the event was bound to is available by default as the calling context of the callback function. That's a really fancy way of saying that the DOM node will be set to the `this` variable:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(this);
}, false);
```

```html
<button type="button">example</button>
```

When you're using inline event handlers in HTML (which you should avoid), `this` is available to be passed to any functions you may want to call:

```js
function click(btn) {
  console.log(btn);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="window.click(this);">example</button>
```

Answer (score 13):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/183/)**.

Yes you can, using **[`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**, for example :

```
element.getAttribute('attribute-name'); //return 'attribute-name' attribute
```

**NOTE:** It's better to pass the object of current clicked element `this` then get the attribute you want :

**HTML :**

```
<button name="X" data-other-attr='XX' onClick="reply_click(this)">Button</button>
```

**JS :**

```
function reply_click(clicked_object)
{
     alert(clicked_object.getAttribute('name'));
     alert(clicked_object.getAttribute('data-other-attr'));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Below is slightly modified code of example you pointed out in the question.

```
<html>
<body>

<form>

<button id="1" name="test1" onClick="reply_click(1)">B1</button>
<button id="2" name="test2" onClick="reply_click(2)">B2</button>
<button id="3" name="test3" onClick="reply_click(3)">B3</button>

<script>
    function reply_click(clicked_id)
    {
        //alert(clicked_id);
        var temp = document.getElementById(clicked_id).getAttribute("name");
        alert(temp);
    }
</script>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

In the example you referenced:

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
```

You could replace `this.id` with `this.name` or `this.dataset` and you would be passing those attributes to the `reply_click` function instead of the ID.

Comment: or you can pass "this" to reply_click function and then inside the function access the button attributes

Comment: @flynorc yes that is what I would do but I wanted to keep it in terms of the answer he referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You want to attach a click handler to the button (`button.addEventListener('click')`), and then access its properties using dot notation just like a regular JavaScript object.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vkrwxmx/